# In Kotlin get array member with their name like in JavaScripe

Tags: kotlin

In Javascript an Array can contain an Object and we can call Object properties by their name.
like

```
const person = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:46};
let fN = person.firstName;
```

How can achieve this in Kotlin.

Comment: What does this have to do with arrays, though? There is no array in your JS code here. It's just an object

Answer (score 3):

You can either try using a `mapOf` or a custom `Person` object.

```kotlin
// mapOf
val person = mapOf("firstName" to "John", "lastName" to "Doe", "age" to 46)
val name = person.get("firstName")
print(name) // John

// Custom class
class Person(val firstname: String, val lastname: String, val age: Int)

val person2 = Person(firstname = "John", lastname = "Doe", age = 46)
print(person2.firstname) // John
```

Comment: While developers used to weakly-typed languages may be more familiar with the first pattern, the second is much more common in strongly-typed languages like Kotlin. Using typed objects is much more powerful, efficient, and robust, too, so it's well worth trying to get used to that way of thinking.

Answer (score 1):

i think the best way is using `data class`

```kotlin
data class Person(val firstName:String ,val lastName:String, val age:Int)

val person1 = Person(firstName = "John", lastName = "Doe", age = 46)
val john = person1.firstName //print "John"


//you can use it in a list

val people = listOf(person1,person2,..)
```

@Edit
`data class` is kotlin special class with some standard functionality and some utility functions included, such as

- equals()/hashCode()
- toString() of the form "Person(name=John,lastName="Doe", age=46)"

> in normal class when you call `println(person1)`, it will print the memory location of that class, but `data class` will print your "data"

- componentN()

> For destructuring like in the javascript
>
> ```kotlin
>   val (firstName,lastNmae,age) = person1
> ```

- copy()

here is the documentation https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html

Comment: This is pretty much the second part of @DarShan's answer

Comment: @Joffrey nope, its different , his answer is a "normal" class , which is quite different with `data class` , a data class as its name "data" , usually used for data holder